# How to get insight of a dependency for the "implementation" configuration?

Tags: gradle

Based on documentation ([4.7.6 - Getting the insight into a particular dependency](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_gradle_command_line.html#sec:dependency_insight)) we can get the insights for a particular configuration specifying the configuration itself.
In the example they are using as configuration `compile`, which is deprecated.
I tried to reproduce the same command replacing, in `build.gradle`, the `compile` configuration with the `implementation` configuration (as I got we are not supposed to use `compile` anymore).
But when I run:

```
gradle dependencyInsight --dependency groovy --configuration implementation
```

Gradle is returning:

```
Execution failed for task ':dependencyInsight'.
Resolving configuration 'implementation' directly is not allowed
```

My `build.gradle` file is the following:

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies{
    implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.10'
}
```

Does it mean I cannot get the insight of a dependency if I'm using `implementation` or is there another way to get it?

Answer (score 23):

I had a similar problem, asked around and got this answer:

The configuration is `compileClasspath`.  If you have variants, there is a configuration per-variant (e.g. for the `release` variant, your configuration would be `releaseCompileClasspath`).

##### Examples

1. No variants: `gradle dependencyInsight --dependency groovy --configuration compileClasspath`;
2. Release variant: `gradle dependencyInsight --dependency groovy --configuration releaseCompileClasspath`

##### Note

There are a few ways to figure out the available configurations.

1. If you add `configurations.each { println it.name }` to your top-level gradle file, the next time you run a task, you'll also get a list of all of your configurations.
2. Run the `dependencies` task on your top-level module - this will output all dependencies for all configurations.  It can be a lot of text, so you could pipe it into a text file for easier searching (`gradle dependencies > dependencies.txt`)

Comment: Can you give me an example, perhaps with the code I posted above? I'm still a beginner with Gradle and Groovy. :)

Comment: @acejazz added an example with your input above!

Comment: if I execute the command you gave with the build file I provided, it returns: "Configuration with name 'releaseCompileClasspath' not found.". Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Oh, I'm giving you the configuration assuming there is a variant, you should just be able to use `compileClasspath` if there are no variants... let me edit my answer...

Comment: So, with `compile` configuration (although deprecated) I can use the same configuration name: `--configuration compile`. With `implementation` configuration I must not use the configuration name, but something else `---configuration compileClasspath`. Am I right?

Comment: @EricBrynsvold this doesn't seem to work for me :( : `Configuration with name 'compileClasspath' not found.`
I'm on Gradle v4.1 (and gradle android plugin v3.0.1). Do you have a link or more info about the configuration 'compileClasspath'? It's not showing up when I print all my configurations like this: `task printConfs {
    configurations.each { println it.name }
}`

Comment: @kip2 I do not know why that configuration does not appear in the list of configurations, but it doesn't on my end either.  If your build has variants (if you have build types, like debug/release and/or flavors, then you have variants), then the full configuration name will include the variant.  For example, I have a debug/release build type, so the configuration name is `debugCompileClasspath` or `releaseCompileClasspath`

Comment: You're right, thank you! I parsed out the actual configurations that gradle expects by first running the dependencies check: `./gradlew -q app:dependencies > dependencies.txt`, then noticed from the text file that configurations such as `debugCompileClasspath` were produced

Comment: What is the real answer for this issue? Can someone please post it as an "answer?"

Answer (score 6):

To get the list of available configuration that can be used with `dependencyInsight`, the easy way is the following :

1. Open gradle view in android studio View > Tool Windows > Gradle
2. Select and run task 'Your App' > Tasks > Android > androidDependencies

Then you have a list of all dependencies for all available configuration, just pick one and run :

```
gradle :mymodule:dependencyInsight --dependency okhttp --configuration flavourDebugCompileClasspath
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is very helpful, and you can also execute it on the command line: `./gradlew :app:androidDependencies` to view all the configurations. Then choose one to execute:

```
./gradlew :app:dependencyInsight  --configuration releaseRuntimeClasspath --dependency com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp
```

---

About `Task :app:dependencyInsight`:

```
e.g: ':app:dependencyInsight --configuration someConf --dependency someDep'
```

Detailed task information for :app:dependencyInsight

Path

```
 :app:dependencyInsight
```

Type

```
 DependencyInsightReportTask (org.gradle.api.tasks.diagnostics.DependencyInsightReportTask)
```

Options

```
 --configuration     Looks for the dependency in given configuration.

 --dependency     Shows the details of given dependency.

 --singlepath     Show at most one path to each dependency
```

Description

```
 Displays the insight into a specific dependency in project ':app'.
```

Group

```
 help
```