# Why did gradlew :app:dependencyInsight fail?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradlew

I try to run this command to list all the dependencies of firebase-messaging library :

```
gradlew :app:dependencyInsight --configuration compile --dependency firebase-messaging
```

but it's return me :

> :app:dependencyInsight No dependencies matching given input were found
>   in configuration ':app:compile'
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 0s 1 actionable task: 1 executed

this is my build.gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1'
}
```

What i did wrong ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because `firebase-messaging` is declared in the `implementation` configuration. `compileClasspath` [should be used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46986264/2003986)

Try :

```
gradlew :app:dependencyInsight --configuration compileClasspath --dependency firebase-messaging
```

edit : using `compileClasspath` won't work with Android as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48913550/2003986)

Using `gradle :app:dependencies` to fetch all dependencies seems to be the cleaner way  to get all the dependencies of `firebase-messaging`

Comment: I update your answer to put in it the output of the command line ... as you see it's not work :(

Comment: Weird thing to do... I updated my answer with a different command

Comment: now i have "Configuration with name 'compileClasspath' not found."

Comment: According to this answer ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/48913550/2003986 ) it won't work on Android, unless you use the old deprecated `compile` configuration :/

Comment: You can use the plain old `gradle dependencies` and look for `firebase-messaging` inside the result. Less convenient but will work.

Comment: thanks @ToYonos ... I updated your answer again, because even with using deprecated compile still not work :(

Comment: You can use --configuration implementation but with suffix "DependenciesMetadata" to show with transitive stuff. e.g. gradlew app:dependencies --configuration implementationDependenciesMetadata

Answer (score 15):

Using `dependencyInsight` with `compileClasspath` works just fine on Android projects (unlike what the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49647837/56285) seems to claim). You just need to prefix it with the full [**build variant**](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants) name!

For example, use **`debugCompileClasspath`** or **`releaseCompileClasspath`** as the configuration param if your project only uses build types.

If product flavours are also in use, the form is **`flavorDebugCompileClasspath`** (insert your own flavour name).

A working example from my project (product flavour `full`, build type `debug`):

```
./gradlew app:dependencyInsight --configuration fullDebugCompileClasspath --dependency gson
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46986264/56285) was useful (after fixing a key typo in it) in figuring this out.

Comment: What does the configuration look like for test and androidTest dependencies?  tried a few combination based on this answer but can't get it right. e.g

```gradle  :base:dependencyInsight --dependency okhttp3 --configuration prodDebugTestCompileClasspath```